# Representing a "Belongs to" relationship in an API endpoint

Tags: design, api, api-design, json

Consider the following pseudo code models:

```
class Post
    int Id
    string Title
    int CategoryId
    Category Category

class Category
    int Id
    string Name
```

Note that Post belongs to Category. This is achieved via a CategoryId foreign key on Post. In the post model, there's also a Category object.

So my questions are:

**1. On a GET request for a post, what would your JSON look like?**

**A -** Just the foreign key (this one seems a little inefficient if the value for the Category name is commonly needed)

```
{
  Id: 1,
  Title: 'My Title',
  CategoryId: 1
}
```

**B -** Just the nested object

```
{
  Id: 1,
  Title: 'My Title',
  Category: {
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'General'
  }
}
```

**C -** Both (same as the actual model)

```
{
  Id: 1,
  Title: 'My Title',
  CategoryId: 1,
  Category: {
    Id: 1,
    Name: 'General'
  }
}
```

**2. Considering the above, what do you do for a PUT/POST?**

I can't seem to find any concrete examples of the best practice to represent this case. Any thoughts, guidance or discussion welcome!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are starting from the wrong end. API design is about what the client/requester requires not about how you represent the data internally.

If the client need the category name then just provide it along with the id (if its useful to the client). As a Post belongs to only one category there is no reason to have anything other than a flat structure.

Answer (score 3):

Structurally, I would reconsider the notion that a post *belongs* to a category. That's a strange way to model the relationship, especially considering a post very well may form a relationship with multiple categories. So in my mind a post *has* multiple categories.

As @James Anderson initiated, you shouldn't think about your API as a result of your persistence structure. Rather, create your API first and later figure out how to query your persistence layer to formulate the response you want.

If I were designing this API then I would just return an array of category titles as a property of the post object. The IDs probably aren't necessary.

For POST and PUT you can either accept category titles and map them to IDs on the back end (returning an error code or possibly creating a new category if a provided title doesn't exist), or accept a category ID. In case of the latter, you'll want a separate API to to GET all known categories and their IDs.

Answer (score 1):

While I agree with James, sometimes for whatever reasons you may want to have objects, so as to have a better representation of the actual data.

In those cases, there are two considerations:

1. Having just CategoryId, if you laways or almost always need the name, will require another request;
2. Having both options is pretty useless since `Post.CategoryId` is not really that different from `Post.Category.Id`, and you have a structure that makes sense, no matter if you have arrays, objects or whatever.

Taking these points into account, in this specific case I would go with nested objects. You have cleaner code, you can easily understand data structures from the JSON (Less mistakes and easier to build new stuff or fix it) and you're avoid unnecessary duplication, in your code and in the JSON object.

Still, it's always good to remember that sometimes nested objects may not be the best option, performance-wise. It's all a matter of what works better for your specific situation.